# Insert Value to a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe

```
0      1      2    3
0  173.0  147.0  161  162.0
1    NaN    NaN   23    NaN
```

I just want to add value a column such as

```
           3
       0 161
       1  23
       2 181
```

But can't go with the approch of `loc` and `iloc`. Because the file can contain columns of any length and I will not know `loc` and `iloc`. Hence Just want to add value to a column. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe need [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement):

```
df.loc[len(df.index), 2] = 181
print (df)
       0      1      2      3
0  173.0  147.0  161.0  162.0
1    NaN    NaN   23.0    NaN
2    NaN    NaN  181.0    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe this will do.

Comment: How to delete perticular value from dataframe. Like `df['2'].astype('str')=='23'` and the rest column's value shift up.

Comment: @Leo - Do you think boolean indexing by `df[df['2'].astype('str')=='23']` ?

Comment: I meant to delete `23.0`  and shift rest column values up.

Comment: @Leo - Sorry, then need invert condition by `df[df['2'].astype('str')!='23']` - filter all rows if `23` not in column `2`

Comment: with `df[df['2'].astype('str')!='23']` whole row I am loosing. Just need to pop out that particular value. Any other way through `df.drop` or something like that.?

Comment: really not easy, is possible replace by `NaN` and then shift? Ir there are multiple `NaN`s ?

Comment: Yeah there are multiple `NaN`s . Data frame is the same as the one you have in your answer.

Comment: How do we replace by `NaN` and then shift ?

Comment: @Leo - Is possible use `df['2'] = pd.Series(df['2'].replace(23, np.nan).dropna().values)` ?

Comment: @jezrael I could not get it, how can i insert value into a row of index 550 to 4th column of a dataframe?

Comment: @panda - use `df.loc[550, 2] = 'your value'`

Answer (score 0):

If that 2x3 dataframe is your original dataframe, you can add an extra row to dataframe by pandas.concat().

For example:

```
pandas.concat([your_original_dataframe, pandas.DataFrame([[181]] , columns=[2] )], axis=0)
```

This will add 181 at the bottom of column 2

Comment: Please provide a little explanation of your code. Code dumps like this are rarely helpful for future visitors.